# Does upsert fire an Update or Insert trigger? Or both?

Tags: apex, trigger, triggercontext

When I do an upsert DML which trigger code will handle it?

1. Insert
2. Update
3. Both

?

Is there a pattern to solve potential duplicate executions if it is 3)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For records that already exist, it will fire updates. For records that are new, it will fire inserts. As a result, an upsert can cause both insert and update triggers to fire if you have both new and existing records in your upsert, but they both won't fire for the same record.

Answer (score 4):

I've got a feeling that when you upsert records it does the inserts and the updates in separate batches. I can't find this documented though!

So for example you should be able to iterate through Trigger.new in an after insert and be confident that every record in Trigger.new is indeed a newly inserted record.

Answer (score 1):

I put some debug into my trigger and found an upsert is running the Insert first and then the Update.

I also have an issue where I want followup processing on the parent records for the inserts and updates but if children of the same parent are involved in both the insert and update the processing runs twice.